# Why does mysql server rpm size become smaller after 8.0.29?

Tags: mysql, centos, rpm

[image]

[image]

A 10 times size change and why?

ref: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/

Answer (score 1):

They've moved lots of non-required stuff to a new "Debug Information" package (`mysql-community-debuginfo-8.0.29-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`). That package isn't available for 8.0.28 and takes 425.3 MB.

It's mentioned in the [MySQL 8.0.29 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-29.html):

> Implemented standard package policy to ship separate debuginfo RPMs for the following platforms: SLES/openSUSE, and community EL6 and EL7. Commercial versions of EL6 and EL7 are now built with the RelWithDebInfo build type instead of Debug, which greatly decreases their size. (Bug #33663811, Bug #33684418, Bug #33664929)